# how to add the values related to the items selected in checkedlistbox

Tags: c#

I want to add all the values  related to the items selected in  checkedListbox to the Textbox.the values to be retrieved from the database.I created table with two columns place and cost.  I populated checkedlistbox with   places from the table and i want to get the result of total cost in the Textbox below the checkedlistbox based on the related costs of selected items from the table.
**database table**
place        cost
hyderabad   3000.00
bombay      2000.00
banglore    5000.00
chennai     7000.00

```
  private void bill_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'testdbDataSet.customer' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.customerTableAdapter.Fill(this.testdbDataSet.customer);
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["conn"]);

        cn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from place", cn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(dr.ItemArray[0]);
        }
```

Comment: Can you add a code sample and an attempt at what you are wanting?

Comment: private void bill_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["conn"]);

            cn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from place", cn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(dr.ItemArray[0]);
            }

Comment: So that is an example, you need to post a code example to get an answer.  Please edit the question with a code example.

Comment: i am talking about the table in the database there is no listview or gridview in my form

Comment: Your question though is about checkedListbox and getting a sum in a checkbox.  It has nothing to do with the database.  Please clearly describe the issue and provide any relevant code.  examples would be database structure, html page, C# code behind.  Without this, we are unable to help you because we can not be certain that our answers will actually answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this should be called elegant or rather chaotic...

```
string places = String.Join("','", checkedListBox.CheckedItems.OfType<string>().ToList());
string query = String.Format("SELECT SUM(cost) FROM yourTable WHERE places IN ('{0}')", places);
```

Pass the query to your db and you should get your sum back.